# Iterating the smart way in a list with LINQ

Tags: c#, list, linq-to-objects

i have this simple class:

```
public class JDEItemLotAvailability
    {
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public int ShortCode { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string PrimaryUnitCode { get; set; }
        public string BranchPlant { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public string Lot { get; set; }
        public int AvailableQuantity { get; set; }
    }
```

This DAL method in my BLL returns a list of them:

```
var returnedLotList = _JDE8dal.GetLotAvailabilityAsList(_lot);
```

I want to do the following in the returned list and i want to do it in the most "elegant" LINQ way.

I want to check if among the list there is a record that matches specific criteria. I have thought of something like this:

```
  var query =
      returnedLotList.Where(l => l.AvailableQuantity != 0 && l.BranchPlant == _mcu && l.Location == _locn)
                               .OrderByDescending(l => l.AvailableQuantity);
```

BUT i want to say that if the above query does not return results i want to take the first of the rest of the list entries.

How can i do that?

Comment: "if the above query does not return results i want to take the first of the rest of the list". That seems like an awkward requirement. Other developers will keep tripping over this. Are you sure this is a good thing?

Comment: the logic behind this goes like: If a lot is not found having quantity in the specific warehouse and location i want it to have, then i dont care bring me one of the other records as an indication. I could go further and make some kind of process instead of getting the first, but i want to get the general idea first...

Comment: How will you know that the record you get is a "not found" record instead of the correct one?  Much better to return an empty list, and then have logic which does something if so.

Comment: @Bobson: hmm this kind of process i was wiondering if i can avoid with just LINQ...

Comment: @e4rthdog - You can, if you want to operate on a "not found" record as if it were a successful match.  If you want to actually know you failed to find a match, you need some standard logic in there too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use `DefaultIfEmpty`

```
//your first query, unaltered
var query =
      returnedLotList.Where(l => l.AvailableQuantity != 0 && l.BranchPlant == _mcu && l.Location == _locn)
                               .OrderByDescending(l => l.AvailableQuantity);

var query2 = query.DefaultIfEmpty(returnedLotList.Take(1));
```

Comment: Note that this iterates the query multiple times if the filteted list is empty. Once for `DefaultIfEmpty`, and once for running `Take(1)`. When iterating (even to get just one item) involves a round trip to the DB, that's a problem. :-)

Comment: @Steven Actually, if the `where` filters a large percentage of the items it's *desirable*.  You first perform a query that does the filtering on the DB side.  If it doesn't return any items you perform another query for one item.  The only way to do it in a single query is to get all items, even those not meeting the criteria.  That's a *significant* network overhead.  Also, given the problem description, the common case is that the filer returns something, so the common case only iterates the result once.

Comment: Don't forget that this question is about LINQ to Objects. The `Where` will always be executed in .NET, never in the database in this case. But when we talk about expression trees and the use of `Queryable`, in that case you are right that this would be the most efficient.

Comment: @Steven Then the consequences of iterating it multiple times are small enough (in this context) to not matter, since you're only taking the first item in the only case where it's iterated multiple times.  The point is that the answer applies equally well (if not more so) to cases involving a database backing.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an extension method that does this:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> WhereOrFirstOfRest<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> collection, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    var filtered = collection.Where(predicate);

    return filtered.Any() ? filtered : collection.Take(1);
}
```

Downside of this extension method is that it iterates the collection multiple times. This can be a problem when you're processing streams (from the database for instance). A more efficient method would be the following:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> WhereOrFirstOfRest<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> collection, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    // Materialize the complete collection.
    collection = collection.ToArray();

    // Filter the collection. ToArray prevents calling the predicate
    // twice for any item.
    var filtered = collection.Where(predicate).ToArray();

    return filtered.Any() ? filtered : collection.Take(1);
}
```

Although this saves you from any possible extra calls to the database, this does create several new arrays under the cover. The most efficient way whould therefore be the following:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> WhereOrFirstOfRest<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> collection, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    T firstItem = default(T);
    bool firstStored = false;
    bool predicateReturnedItems = false;

    foreach (var item in collection)
    {
        if (!firstStored)
        {
            firstItem = item;
            firstStored = true;   
        }

        if (predicate(item))
        {
            yield return item;
            predicateReturnedItems = true;
        }
    }

    if (!predicateReturnedItems && !first)
    {
        yield return firstItem;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this iterates the query multiple times if it's non-empty.  Once for `Any`, and once for the actual results.  When iterating (even to get just one item) involves a round trip to the DB, that's a problem.

Comment: @Servy: That's absolutely true. I was already writing an improved version before I read your comment. We're on the same page :-)

Comment: You're trying to do to much at once.  As my answer shows, DefaultIfEmpty already does most all of this for you, you're mostly just re-implementing it and also mixing in `Where`, as opposed to just calling the two existing functions independently.  If this is actually done enough to warrant making it's own function (which I doubt) you can still re-use those methods.  The whole implementation could just be `collection.Where(predicate).DefaultIfEmpty(collection.Take(1));` given the definition as you defined it.

Comment: @Servy: See my comment on your answer. Your code will also trigger a second query :-)

Comment: And see my response.  This code will require the entire collection to be pulled into memory, even all of the items that don't meet the filter.  By not using `Where` you're not allowing that filter to be performed on the database.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand but maybe something like this:

```
var firstMatch = returnedLotList.FirstOrDefault(l => l.AvailableQuantity != 0 && 
                                                     l.BranchPlant == _mcu && 
                                                     l.Location == _locn);
if (firstMatch != null)
    return firstMatch;
int max = returnedLotList.Max(l => l.AvailableQuantity);
return returnedLotList.First(l => l.AvailableQuantity == max);
```

- FirstOrDefault will return null if no match
- I think it is a good idea to split the queries up to make it clearer what is happening.